# Reminder is not working

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, reminders

I want to remind the user based on time,but cannot achieve using this code,please give me any solution.This is my code:

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.StartDate date];

    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSDate *date1=[pickerDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = date1;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    //notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval =NSCalendarUnitWeekday;
    notifyAlarm.soundName =UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody =self.EventText.text;
    //notifyAlarm.alertLaunchImage=@"in.png";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: and how are you checking it is working or not

Comment: yeah am checked but cannot remind

Comment: how did you check that is what i have asked

Comment: please give me the any solution for this problem

Comment: sorry can you please explain briefly

Comment: you actually need to explain your problem clearly. this is your code but what happens after you run it and what was supposed to happen. how did you do your testing etc

Comment: ok.i want to add the eventtitle and event date and then based on the event date alert the user achieved by UILocalnotification.In my problem is events are added but cannot remind the user.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Comment: followed this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in didFinishLaunch method in appdelegate.m

```
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                            UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                            UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                     categories:nil];
            [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else {

            [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much,i was spend last one week for this task,i but cannot found this solution